# Copying a virtualPC vm

Tags: virtualization, virtual-pc

How do I clone an existing virtualPC (2007) vm ?

I am setting up my development environment and want to clone it, and also keep one as a backup that has all my baseline installs.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a copy of the vhd (the virtual hard disk) and vmc (the settings) files.  You may need to edit the vmc to point to the renamed vhd file (if you choose to use a different name)

Alternately make a new virtual machine, say that it's based on an existing vhd and point it to the copy.

Comment: so when its based on an existing, it won't effect the existing one obviously right?

Comment: If you point it to the copy, it won't affect the original. If you really want to be sure, make the original VHD read-only - VirtualPC will respect this flag.

Comment: Like Piskvor says, if the "existing" is the *copy* of the vhd, you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Because I Virtual PC is just a couple of files, you can just copy the Virtual PC file (VMC) and Virtual Hard Drive(s) (vhd) and you've cloned the device.

Don't forget you can also use the Undo disk feature to reset all the changes made to the Virtual PC over a session.

Answer (score 0):

Each Virtual PC has its own folder and set of files; simply make a copy of its folder and you have a second copy of the machine.

I believe by default it's in My Documents > My Virtual Machines.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you run [NewSid](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897418.aspx) on the copied machine if you ever plan on booting both machines (doesn't matter whether in the same time or not).